# Virtual Machine not launching Gazebo

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu-16.04, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am using the beta version of ROS as well as Ubuntu 16.04. When attempting to launch gazebo I get the following error:

```
mroscoe@ubuntu:~$ gazebo
VMware: vmw_ioctl_command error Invalid argument.
```

I have checked online and cannot find a solution and was hoping someone here may have run into it and knows how to work around it.

Results from running **GLXGEARS:**

```
mroscoe@ubuntu:~$ glxgears 
6223 frames in 5.0 seconds = 1244.564 FPS
4971 frames in 5.0 seconds = 993.205 FPS
6041 frames in 5.0 seconds = 1208.158 FPS
5833 frames in 5.0 seconds = 1166.566 FPS
5299 frames in 5.0 seconds = 1059.721 FPS
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13214/virtual-machine-not-launching-gazebo/) by [badrobit](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2344/badrobit/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-05-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-05-04**:
Can you run `glxgears`?

**Comment by [badrobit](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2344/badrobit/) on 2016-05-05**:
Yes it runs with no issues (I attached the output to the question itself).

**Comment by [derek](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2620/derek/) on 2016-05-30**:
the same issue:
$ gazebo
VMware: vmw_ioctl_command error Invalid argument

**Comment by [Tim Dupont](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2630/tim-dupont/) on 2016-06-02**:
Clean/Fresh Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS Kinetic Kame install in VMware Fusion Professional Version 8.1.1 (3771013): Gazebo crashes with the same error message.

"VMware: vmw_ioctl_command error Invalid argument."

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2016-06-02**:
Can you try running `gzserver --verbose`? And then `gzclient --verbose`?

**Comment by [jbongers](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2662/jbongers/) on 2016-06-15**:
I have the same problem. I tried running glxgears and it worked. I also tried running 'gzserver --verbose' and then gzclient. gzserver --verbose ran perfectly but when i tried to ran gzclient --verbose i got this message: Aborted (core dumped) , and it crashed.

Anybody knows how to fix the problems so that I can run gazebo?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2016-06-15**:
Run gzclient in gbd, and post the backtrace.

**Comment by [jbongers](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2662/jbongers/) on 2016-06-16**:
Thnx for replying:

I ran gzclien in gbd an this are my results: ( I give you the last 6 lines if this is OK?)

VMware: vmw_ioctl_command error Invalid argument.
[New Thread 0x7fff97fff700 (LWP 3792)]

Thread 1 "gzclient" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff647d418 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
54  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.

**Comment by [rash_einstein](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2693/rash_einstein/) on 2016-07-05**:
Hey. Please did you find a fix yet?

**Comment by [jonbinney](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/852/jonbinney/) on 2016-07-07**:
I've gotten then same error using gazebo (from ROS kinetic repos) on 16.04 in VMWare workstation 12.1.1. My host machine is a linux laptop with both nvidia and intel graphics. Interesting, I only see the problem when i have nvidia-prime set to the nvidia graphics.

**Comment by [phillipchengyi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2766/phillipchengyi/) on 2016-08-15**:
me too, please help

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I was able to launch Gazebo 7.1.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 by unchecking "Accelerate 3D Graphics" option in the virtual machine settings. Seems like the problem has to do with how VMWare handles the graphics acceleration.

---

Originally posted by [m_elfar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2702/m_elfar/) with karma: 11 on 2016-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [buckmole](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2769/buckmole/) on 2016-08-27**:
I tried your solution, and then it worked, the message "vmw_ioctl_command error Invalid argument" was gone. I have no idea why the "Accelerate 3D Graphics" has the impact on the issue. It just happens in Ubuntu 14 and higher version.

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2835/alienmon/) on 2016-10-26**:
Thanks it solved my problem of not being able to open fetch robot in gazebo simulation! It's strange tho, cause I actually can other robots except for that particular robot.

**Comment by [tabuzzy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3012/tabuzzy/) on 2017-01-16**:
I've unselected the "Accelerate 3D Graphics" option, however, now when trying to log into the guest account, i just get a blank screen. has this happened to anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I had the same problem with:
Windows 8 host --> VMware 12.1.1 --> Ubuntu 16.04 guest
Gazebo 7.5

I solved it with the following environmental variable presumably shrinking down the graphics instruction set to OpenGL2.

> $ export SVGA_VGPU10=0

Gazebo starts now and runs compared to the not 3D accelerated way pretty smooth on a T460p if the resolution of the VM guest system is not too high (<< 4K).

To make the change permanent use:

> $ echo "export SVGA_VGPU10=0" >> ~/.profile

Sideote: If you'd add it to `~/.bashrc` starting gazebo from gui or other terminals than bash would still be broken.

The entire idea is from **Hugo Rodde**, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/stellarium/+bug/1577494 .

---

Originally posted by [MaEtUgR](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3007/maetugr/) with karma: 21 on 2017-01-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aleangelico](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7846/aleangelico/) on 2019-01-05**:
this worked for me, VMWare 14 with Lubuntu + ROS Melodic and Gazebo 9. Sorry I dont have enough points to upvote your question.

**Comment by [asantanna-applied](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/11913/asantanna-applied/) on 2019-05-29**:
Worked for me also.  And unlike unchecking "accelerate Graphics", this solution keeps things fast!
Thanks!

**Comment by [BWMiller](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/12478/bwmiller/) on 2019-06-12**:
Agree, worked VMWare Fusion 10.1.6, Ubuntu 18.04.2, Gazebo 9.